# Why does Java HashMap contain null values in the debug view

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap

While debugging I found a strange behavior.

I got a `HashMap<Integer, Set<Term>>` (Term is a class which only contains a String) the normal `toString()` shows this:

[image]

When I click the table property of the HashMap I get this:

[image]

My Question now, why are there null values in the table `toString()` ?

Edit: Thanks for your fast answers! If I could, I would accept all of them...

Comment: just skip that line and point your debugger to the next line, and then check the value of your HashMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashMap is a Map implementation that's crucial feature is constant time O(1) lookup.

The only data structure in computer science with constant time lookup is an array of fixed length. When you initialise the HashMap it's creating a fixed length array that it will expand when your entries exceed the current array's size.

Edit: @kutschkem has pointed out that java.util.HashMap expands its fixed length array when the number of entries is around 80% of the current array's size, rather than when the entries exceed the current array's size.

Comment: actually, I think it is more like 80% of the current array's size. See my answer.

Comment: @kutschkem this depends upon what HashMap implementation you use, I was trying to keep my answer on more of the conceptual level. I think the main point here is that a HashMap must use a fixed length array to get the O(1) (assuming no collisions) lookup and that's why we're seeing the nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Map implementation you are using is working with a starting set of HashBuckets some of which are NULL at beginning (determined by initialCapacity). If you exceed the number of entries it will start creating more HashBuckets / slots for your Objects. Think of this as a growth reserve the HashMap automatically creates for you.

Read more:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

The HashMap stores its entries in a hashtable. That is an array, and the hash function maps the key to one of the array entries (also called hash buckets).

The hash buckets are always at least 20% empty. If they are not, then the array is resized to make sure there is enough free space.

The reason is that as the hash table gets filled up, collisions between hashes get more and more likely. You lose all advantages of the HashMap if collisions are too frequent. Too full, and your HashMap would be no better than a LinkedList (yes, LinkedList, not ArrayList). It would probably be even worse.

Answer (score 1):

That is how a hash map work: a large array (`table`), and for some key the following table entry is tried:

```
table[key.hashCode() % table.length]
```

That table slot then is used. Rehashing is used if there already is a key that is not `equals(key)`.
So initially the table contains only nulls, and has size `initialCapacity`. The array can be grown when the hash map becomes too filled (`loadFactor`).

Answer (score 1):

The HashMap uses internally an array to store the entries. Very much simplified, it does something like `array_index = hashcode % array_length` (again: very simplified, as it also needs to take care of hash collisions etc). This internal array is typically larger than the number of elements you store in the HashMap -- otherwise, the array would have to be resized every time you add an element to it. So what you see as `null` are the yet unused slots in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior.

There are null values because the table array was initialized as being filled with nulls, and uses null to indicate that there are no values stored in that hash bucket.

The toString() function provided doesn't skip over them because seeing them was useful to the folds debugging the HashMap implementation.

If you want to see the contents without the nulls, you'll have to write your own display function, either by subclassing HashMap and overriding toString() or by providing a convenience function somewhere in your code.